# Add Alternate Universe Time Zones to Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, time

The [Elite: Dangerous](https://www.elitedangerous.com/) game universe operates in real-time, at a 1:1 ratio, with a time offset of ["UTC +1286 years"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite:_Dangerous#Gameplay).

I know how to add another time zone to the system tray clock, and setting the extra zone to UTC would generally be sufficient to help keep track of the current time in relation to in-game schedules. However, I really want to go that one step extra - set the secondary time zone to be fully in-sync with the in-game *date* as well.

Is there a way to add a custom time zone to Windows 7 and/or Windows 10, that has an offset of over a thousand years?

---

Sidenote: It turns out a custom time zone for Elite: Dangerous wouldn't quite work properly anyway. This is because the Elite: Dangerous universe is just two years off in the leap year cycle - so, every other year, we'd have a February 29th that belongs in one universe but not the other.

See [my question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286164/how-in-sync-is-the-elite-dangerous-calendar-compared-to-real-time) for more info.

That said, I'm still interested in the answer to this question here. I'm sure it will be useful for other scenarios.

Comment: You are better of running a third-party application.  Windows only has a single system clock, the additional clocks you see, are simply adjusted off that single time with a timezone adjustment.  Which is the reason additional clocks, don't allow you, to set the date on them.  There is no way to have a system clock for the current year, and a system clock for the for the current year + 1286 years